# Align Image in Table and add Title Header row

Tags: html, css, powershell

I would like for the image in the script below to be aligned to the top right corner above the table. Currently it is aligned to the left above the table, is this possible? Also I would like to add an additional title row at the top of the Table spanning the width of the table with a fixed title, is this possible without breaking the table?

```
#Set variables
$image = "C:\Scriptrepository\XXXXX.gif"
$ImageBits = [Convert]::ToBase64String((Get-Content $image -Encoding Byte))
$ImageHTML = "<img src=data:image/gif;base64,$($ImageBits) alt=XXXXX;/>"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date -Format F
$Post = "<br><br> Members of $ADGroupName <br> Generated on $CurrentDate"

#Function for alternating table colour rows
function global:Set-AlternatingRows {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$Line,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$CSSEvenClass,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$CSSOddClass
    )

    Begin {
        $ClassName = $CSSEvenClass
    }
    Process {
        if ($Line.Contains("<tr><td>")) {
            $Line = $Line.Replace("<tr>","<tr class=""$ClassName"">")
            if ($ClassName -eq $CSSEvenClass) {
                $ClassName = $CSSOddClass
            } else {
                $ClassName = $CSSEvenClass
            }
        }
        return $Line
    }
}

#Function to validate request and create variable from input
function global:GetADGroupMembersrecursively {
    Write-Host "Enter Distribution List / AD Group name:" -ForegroundColor Green
    $global:ADGroupName = Read-Host
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ADGroupName)) { 
        cls
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor red "Cannot be blank, please re-enter AD Group / distribution list name" | Out-Null
        GetADGroupMembersRecursively 
    }
    $global:DLCheck = DSQuery group -Name "$ADGroupName"
    if ($DLCheck -eq $null) { 
        cls
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor red "Did not find AD Group / Distribution List, please verify this is the correct name" | Out-Null
        GetADGroupMembersRecursively
    }
}

GetADGroupMembersRecursively

$Head = @"
<style>
BODY {font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt; color: #4C607B;}
TABLE{margin: auto; font-family: Segoe UI; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888; width: 100%;height :50px;}
TH, TD {border: 1px solid #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse;padding: 3px;}
TH {font-size: 1.2em; background-color: #003366; color: #ffffff; }
TD {color: #000000; }
 .even { background-color: #efefef; }
 .odd { background-color: #c0c0c0; }
TR { background: #b8d1f3; }
H4 {font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: #4C607B;align=right;}
H5 {font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt; color: #4C607B;align=right;}
</style>
"@ 

#Table creation
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroupName -Recursive |
    Get-ADUser -pr GivenName, Surname, mail, sAMAccountName |
    Select-Object GivenName, Surname, mail, sAMAccountName |
    sort Surname |
    ConvertTo-Html -Head $head -Body $ImageHTML -PostContent $Post -As Table |
    Set-AlternatingRows -CSSOddClass odd -CSSEvenClass even |
    Out-File C:\ScriptRepository\Results\$ADGroupName.htm
Invoke-Item C:\ScriptRepository\Results\$ADGroupName.htm
```

Comment: First, work out what the _result_ should be - what HTML and CSS will provide the output you want? Once you have that, writing the PowerShell code to generate it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: It generates a table from an AD lookup, the Table is working fine its just the positioning of the Image above the Table and to the right and adding a row at the top of the table with a Title I am having trouble with.

Comment: Build the web page with a dummy table to look like you want, with the correct HTML and CSS. Do it by hand, if necessary - you just want something that looks right, even if it doesn't have "real" data. Then, using that as a guide, you should be able to work out what HTML and CSS your script should emit to wrap around the table that you are creating from the AD lookup.

Comment: Thankyou for your time @Jeff, My HTML / CSS skills are almost non-existant unfortunately for me. Ansgar's suggestion below has worked for aligning the image however I am still unsure on how to add an addition fixed Title row to the Table. The Title would be generated from the following: "Members of $ADGroupName  generated on $CurrentDate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the image in a block-level element (`<p>` for instance), and align that element to the right:

```
...
$ImageHTML = "<p class='pic'><img src=.../></p>"
...
$Head = @"
<style>
...
p.pic {text-align: right}
...
</style>
"@
...
```

Comment: Cheers Ansgar, I added  p.pic {text-align: right} to $Head as suggested and amended with your suggestion $ImageHTML = "<p class='pic'><img src=data:image/gif;base64,$($ImageBits) alt=NHSImprovement;/>" It works perfectly. Thank you very much for your time and help, it is very much appreciated.